# Does not finish booting from USB

Tags: boot, usb

While following the instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) (either 12.10 or 12.04)
It begins good. Brings up the selection menu to boot from USB or to install. Then starts booting fine but never finishes. It gets stuck on the purple screen with the Ubuntu logo. The progress dots freeze. If I leave it, after a while, the screen gets mangled with random boxes as if the graphics card is going bad.

This is on a Asus G51J ... should I assume there is some type of a driver issue ?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/162075/44179) post?

Comment: So far, while I try, no version of Ubuntu in any configuration will run on the G51J with the Nvidia 360M graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

It's a driver issue that I solved doing this:

1. Press **any key** before the Ubuntu installation welcome screen (to open the ["Ubuntu CD Advanced Welcome Page Options"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions?action=show&redirect=BootParameters#Ubuntu_CD_Advanced_Welcome_Page_Options).
2. Press **F6** and select the **nomodeset** option and finish the installation.
3. Hold the **shift** key while booting from the new installation (to access the GRUB options) and select the [**recovery mode**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode#Booting_into_recovery_mode) in the GRUB options.
4. Using the recovery mode, enable Internet access and open the root console to execute this commands:

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install nvidia-current 
    exit
```

Comment: THANK you !
That was exactly the issue. All is good now.